# OpenLayers parsing GeoJSON error 'Uncaught TypeError: feature.getId is not a function'

Tags: javascript

With the following code i am trying to get coordinates from polygon drawing on map but i get this console error instead "Uncaught TypeError: feature.getId is not a function"

```
const drawInteraction = new Draw({
  type:'Polygon',
  freehand:true
})
map.addInteraction(drawInteraction);
drawInteraction.on('drawend',function(e){
  let parser= new GeoJSON();
  let drawnFeatures = parser.writeFeatureObject([e.feature]);
  console.log(drawnFeatures);
})
```

Comment: where have you implemented feature.getId??

Answer (score 0):

Actually i found the error it is
let drawnFeatures = parser.writeFeatures([e.feature]);
and not
`let drawnFeatures = parser.writeFeatureObject([e.feature]);`